# WordPress redux framework - Add custom fiedl to post type from child theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, redux-framework

I have a WordPress theme with a few post types, the theme runs on redux framework.

I want to add to a specific post type a custom field from the functions.php file in child theme without editing core files/installing plugins for it.

How could i do it? looking for something like:

```
if(is_post_type("some_post_type")&& is_admin_single_editor()){
     // Add custom field to edit screen
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That's a bit of a loaded question. Does the theme use Redux metaboxes? If it's only a panel, then this is not a "Redux" question, but a WordPress only question.

You need to specify more details.  ;)

Comment: Yes, it is. All of meta pages in admin pages with meta data are by redux.

Comment: Ok, then you need only change the post_type argument for a given panel, and all the options will appear. See details here: https://docs.reduxframework.com/extensions/metaboxes/